# Symfony filter to run before and possibly skip the controller

Tags: caching, symfony1, filter, symfony-1.4

The idea of the desired filter is to check the memcached for page content with url as a key and if found, return it to client directly from cache and skip the controller altogether. Storing would be done in separate filter, which is the easy part. I'm aware i could write it to action's preExecute() but filters would offer more elegant solution (could turn them off for dev envs).

In other words - is there a smart way for a filter to push the response to client and skip going to action?

Comment: FWIW, I haven't delved deeply yet into symfony 2, but this is the sort of thing for which it's being designed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you have a look at overwriting the sfExecutionFilter.

It's the last filter in the default filters.yml, which means it's the first executed.
This is what is responsible for calling your action's executeXXX method and loading associated view and bunch of other things.

Presumably you could write your own filter the extends sfExecutionFilter and overwrite it's functionality to skip executing the controller it the output is cached.

You can find the default filters.yml @ %SYMFONY_DIR%/config/config/filters.yml

Comment: I think that's the correct answer. I did it somewhat differently to myself but considering refactoring my logic using your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing such a filter is quite easy. Actually similar solution exists in symfony.

Look at the default caching filter (*sfCacheFilter* class). It's doing something similar to what you're looking for.

**Alternative path**

It is already possible to use memcache directly by changing the default file caching to memcache.

In your factories file you're able to switch cache driver (apps/yourapp/config/factories.yml or config/factories.yml):

```
all:
  view_cache:
    class: sfMemcacheCache
```

You could do the same with memcached but as symfony doesn't provide sfMemcachedCache class you would have to implement it on your own.

This way you could reuse existing caching framework and take advantage of cache.yml files.

Comment: i needed a little more control over the cache in my app (paired url/agent grouping etc) so i set the writing to memcached part to filter and moved reading out to preExecute(). Still working on it though so.. will accept your answer once it's all done. Thanks!